# The server encountered an internalException org.hibernate.validator.InvalidStateException: validation failed for: com.contact.ContactRegistration

Tags: hibernate, validation, struts2, struts, hibernate-validator

I am really new to Struts and Hibernate. I am working on a web app where user fills a form. I have to put some validations on some fields, I am trying to use validations in POJO class on some fields.

Like `@Past on Date`, `@Max on int`.

But its not working properly and throwing these exceptions.

```
HTTP Status 500 validation
failed for: com.contact.ContactRegistration
type Exception report
message validation failed for: com.contact.ContactRegistration
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from       fulfilling this request.
exception
org.hibernate.validator.InvalidStateException: validation failed for:    com.contact.ContactRegistration
org.hibernate.validator.event.ValidateEventListener.validate(ValidateEventListener.java:148)
org.hibernate.validator.event.ValidateEventListener.onPreInsert(ValidateEventListener.java:172)
org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:119)
org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:42)
org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:298)
org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
```

I have included these jars.

1. `classmate-1.0.0`
2. `hibernate-validator.jar`
3. `jboss-logging-3.1.0-CR2`
4. `validation-api-1.1.0.Final`

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate validations are performed when you are trying to persist an object. The exception stacktrace shows that you are saving transient instance in Hibernate session.

It throws an exception because the object being validated has invalid values. The exception allows you to rollback the current transaction.

The `org.hibernate.validator.InvalidStateException` could be caught by your code to get some info for the error happened. It has a method `getInvalidValues()` which returns validation errors.